# Mysql query top 10 soccer scorers with one query

Tags: mysql

I have problem to making soccer/football top 10 scorers.

I have something like this:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bcc81/6/0)

```
SELECT p.*, count(*) as num_goals
FROM match_goals g 
INNER JOIN match_players p ON g.match_player_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN matches m ON m.id = p.match_id
WHERE p.is_deleted = 0 AND 
      g.is_own_goal = 0 AND
      m.season_id = 2
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY num_goals DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I have same player scored different games goals.

It doesnt sum.. shows 6 goals and 2 goals.. But it is same player.. and in same team..

Comment: My brain is shutting down at the end of the day - but if I just run select * from your above query using the same constraints it only yields 1 player, who scored 8 goals in 2 matches - I don't know if that's from your dummy data or maybe only one player scored for that season.

Comment: The data set isn't representative of the problem

Comment: Please provide **minimal yet complete** sample data which is able to cover all the cases (including edgecases).